# How to import any UML/XMI files to StarUML?

Tags: uml, documentation, xmi, visual-paradigm, staruml

I am trying to import a UML Diagram (of a C++ project) I designed in a program called Visual Paradigm.

This program allows me to save the UML diagram in various formats

[image])

and when I choose the XMI format (supported by StarUML through an extension
) it allows me to pick the XMI version to save the file

[image]

The problem comes when I try to import the file in StarUml: when I try to load an XMI file (I tried every version) that cames from V.P. it says "Failed to load the file";

[image]

On the other hand, if I save the diagram into UML2 format and then I try to open it, StarUML just does nothing.

Do You have any suggestions to work this problem out?

Here is a zip archive with another simpler project containing source code and XMI files (different versions) generated by Visual Paradigm: [Project.rar](https://cloud.degoo.com/e/drive-s0cdsh3qbi9t)

Comment: can you try with a simple project containing for instance just one class, allowing you to give us the XMI produced in the two cases if that reduced project cannot be imported ?

Comment: XMI transfer works only per coincidence. If you're lucky, fine. If not: ask the tool provider how/whether the source from the producer is supported. Most tools put their own flavor inside XMI and others either get confused or give up.

Answer (score 3):

In StarUML Github Issues there is something very similar to you [issue](https://github.com/staruml/staruml-xmi/issues/16).

I had the same problem and the workaround proposed worked for me, search for
file "xmi-reader.js", then change in function "loadFromFile" the line:

```
var XMINode = dom.getElementsByTagName('XMI')[0]
```

to

```
var XMINode = dom.getElementsByTagName('xmi:XMI')[0]
```

Adding the name space "xmi:" to the name of the element makes it work.

Depending on you version of StarUML the file name could be xmi21-reader.js .

Comment: Thanks a lot! On Windows 7 the file to edit is `C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roaming\StarUML\extensions\user\staruml.xmi\xmi21-reader.js`